# EF Core : define 1 to 1 AND 1 to many between the same tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1, ef-core-2.2

I have two tables, for the sake of argument let's call them `Profile` and `Session`. A `Profile` has a currently active session (optional), and all sessions have to be linked to a profile (even those that are not active).

[image: table definition]

So what we have is a 1 to 1 relationship between `Session` and `Profile` on `CurrentSessionId` and also a 1 to many relationship between `Profile` and `Session`.

The question is how to build this in Entity Framework code-first?

I have my two entities

```
public class Profile
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Session CurrentSession { get; set; }
}

public class Session
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

and two type configurations

```
public class ProfileTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Profile>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Profile> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Profile");
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder.HasOne(x => x.CurrentSession)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Profile>("CurrentSessionId")
            .HasConstraintName("FK_CurrentSession_Profile")
            .IsRequired(false);
    }
}

public class SessionTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Session>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Session> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Session");
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder.HasOne<Profile>()
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey("ProfileId")
            .HasConstraintName("FK_Profile_CurrentSession")
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

All of this generates the database schema as expected with the correct columns and foreign keys. The problem comes when I try and insert a profile into the database

```
var profile = new Profile
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    CurrentSession = new Session
    {
         Id = Guid.NewGuid()
    }
};

ctx.Profiles.Add(profile);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

At which point I get a `SqlException` saying

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Profile_CurrentSession"

Looking in profiler the insert does not include the `Profile` record and it is only trying to insert the `Session`

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [Session] ([Id], [ProfileId])
VALUES (@p0, @p1);
',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier,@p1 uniqueidentifier',@p0='AE96BD5F-FB0D-4E02-8E97-FBEFE4EF1382',@p1='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
```

Is what I am trying to do possible? Should it be defined in another way?

- EF Core version: 2.2.1
- Database Provider: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
- Operating system: Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by explicitly defining the keys and then by creating the profile and session separately before setting the current session.

The entities

```
public class Profile
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? CurrentSessionId { get; set; }
    public Session CurrentSession { get; set; }
}

public class Session
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ProfileId { get; set; }
}
```

The type configuartion

```
public class ProfileTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Profile>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Profile> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Profile");
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        builder.HasMany<Session>()
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ProfileId)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_Profile_CurrentSession")
            .IsRequired();

        builder.HasOne(x => x.CurrentSession)
            .WithOne()
            .HasForeignKey<Profile>("CurrentSessionId")
            .HasConstraintName("FK_CurrentSession_Profile")
            .IsRequired(false);
    }
}

public class SessionTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Session>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Session> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Session");
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    }
}
```

The program.

```
var profileId = Guid.NewGuid();
var sessionId = Guid.NewGuid();

var profile = new Profile
{
    Id = profileId,
};

var session = new Session
{
    Id = sessionId,
    ProfileId = profileId
};

ctx.Profiles.Add(profile);
ctx.Sessions.Add(session);
ctx.SaveChanges();

profile.CurrentSession = session;
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

If you try to apply the session directly to the profile, it creates a circular dependency, so you have to create them first and save. Then, set the current and save again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, looks like I would have to dirty up my class definitions + calling code to achieve this though and also save to the db twice :-(

Comment: This could be considered a bug since it's not an actual circular dependency. You can post this issue on EF Core's Github page. https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues